# Where can I find the documentation about using type parameters as function parameters?

Tags: scala, typeclass

I found the following example in the cats [docs](http://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses.html):

```
trait Monoid[A] {
  def empty: A
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}
def combineAll[A](list: List[A], A: Monoid[A]): A = list.foldRight(A.empty)(A.combine)
```

How come one can write `A: Monoid[A]` as a parameter of the method?

Thanks

Comment: `A` on the left has nothing to do with `A` on the right. It's just a variable name. Could be `foo: Monoid[A]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala has separate namespaces for types and values, so a type and a value can have same name without a conflict, and (as Dima's comment says) without any relationship between them. `A` in `A: ...` is a value; `A` in `...[A]` is a type.

Giving them same name is just a convention used by cats, so that calls like `A.empty` "look like" they are calls on the type `A` (or on its companion object), but in fact they aren't.

Comment: Thank you. It was confusing though.

Comment: I meant the practice of using in this context the same name for the type parameter and the funtion parameter.